# How to setup local server for wordpress site with git

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git

I'm working on a WordPress site via Sourcetree. The previous dev working on this project had set up a local server with Docker, however I have no experience with this.

My question is - how can I connect to `localhost` to start developing?

**Note-**

1. I've downloaded mysql, xampp and wordpress locally
2. I have experience developing wordpress sites locally (via an FTP such as FileZilla), however I've never done so with git included.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow these instructions:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/setting-up-xampp/

Probably one thing that you are not doing properly is that your project doesn't sit in xampp/htdocs/myproject as that way you can access it through http://localhost/myproject